# Programmatically select multiple listbox items using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, listbox

I have a multiple list box.

In View,

```
        <select name="cars" multiple class="listMutiple top5">
            <option ng-repeat="u in users" value="{{u}}">{{u}}</option>
        </select>
```

In controller,

```
        $scope.users = ["aaaaa","bbbbb","ccccc","ddddd","eeeee","fffff"]
```

I have a select all checkbox

I need to select all options(same kind of selection happen when i click on any item in the listbox) in the listbox when i click on the select all checkbox. I am not sure how to achieve that.

Anyone please help me.

Comment: Give the neat explanation for this for e.g show any pages like this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ng-selected directive:

```
<option ng-selected="u.selected" ng-repeat="u in users" 
        value="{{u.name}}">{{u.name}}>
</option>
```

See the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jf2p46sj/)